# mschart how to position y axis label inside column and rotate text 90 degrees

Tags: mschart

How can the y-axis label be positioned inside a column and rotate text 90 degrees?

Currently, the y-axis label appears above the column.
When the column bar is at the max height and touches the top of the chart area, the y label appears within the column bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean data labels, then right-click on the data label and choose "Format Data Labels."  You can center the text with LabelOptions/LabelPosition, and you can orient the text with Alignment/TextDirection.
(This is for doing the change manually.  Doing it in a program would be similar.)